# Passing JSON model and a separate value to an API via POST

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a .NET Core 3 project and When using Postman to test my API, I usually test a POST request like this:

```
http://localhost/api/CarEngine
```

Then in the Body section, I'll have a JSON representation of the new `CarEngine`:

```cs
{
    "engineId": "495ssueyq271",
    "source": "AUS",
    "material": "Cast Iron",
    "displacement": "4.7l",
    "fuelType": "gas"
}
```

The API endpoint will then look something like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<CarEngine>> PostCarEngine( CarEngine carEngine)
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

But I need to modify this endpoint now to also pass along a `countryId`. The `countryId` is not part of the `CarEngine` model, but the API needs to update another model with that `countryId`. So the POST method will look like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<CarEngine>> PostCarEngine(String countryId, CarEngine carEngine)
{
    // ...
}
```

I tried passing the countryId in the JSON, but that doesn't work because `countryId` is not a property of `CarEngine`. Is there a way to pass the JSON model and also something that doesn't belong to the model in the same API call?

Comment: You can create a new model that inherits from CarEngine, you could make countryId a URI parameter or query string, or you can use composition in your model and have a model that contains CarEngine and countryId. There are many choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the following method to transfer the "countryId" value and "carEngine" object.

1. Transfer the `countryId` value in the url and put the `carEngine` object in the request body.

   Modify your code as below:

   ```
    [HttpPost("countryId")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CarEngine>> PostCarEngine(string countryId, CarEngine carEngine)
    {
   ```

   Then, the PostMan screenshot as below:

   [image]
2. Create a new ViewModel which contains the countryId and all of the CarEngine's properties. Then, transfer it in the request body.
3. Transfer the data from the form.

   The PostMan screenshot like this:

   [image]

   By using this method, you could use the `[FromForm]` attribute to get the value.

   ```
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CarEngine>> PostCarEngine([FromForm]string countryId, [FromForm]CarEngine carEngine)
    {
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. You can pass countryId as query string and carEngine as post body
2. or Second way, You can both as `content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and in post body as `countryId=1&carEngine={Id:1,Body:'x44'}` (encoded format: `countryId%3D1%26carEngine%3D%7BId%3A1%2CBody%3A'x44'%7D`)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, change your api method to this:

```
[HttpPost)]
public async Task<ActionResult<CarEngine>> CreateCarEngine([FromQuery] string countryId, [FromBody] CarEngine carEngine)
{ ... }
```

The url will look like:
`POST http://localhost/api/CarEngine?countryId=123`

`countryId` will be query param.
`carEngine` will be body param serialized to json.

Comment: I think you've got one an extraneous ) in the HttpPost attribute